# Powering a NodeMCU as well as a GSM module

Tags: esp8266, power, nodemcu, gsm

I'm trying to connect a GSM module(sim800L) with a NodeMCU to execute remote operations. But the GSM module cannot be powered using the NodeMCU. So, what are the other ways to power the board as well as the module. Also I want to connect directly to a wall power supply instead of using a battery.

Comment: connect them to the supply in parallel.

Comment: So, I would have to use a 5V 2A power adapter and then connect the devices in parallel to it. Right?

Comment: Check if your SIM800L can actually take 5V. If so, then you can connect both in parallel.

Comment: the sim800l module operates between 3.7 to 4.7 V

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of researching, I have found the following solution:-

A DC-DC buck converter (such as the LM2596) can convert a 12 V 2A rated power supply down to 4 V (the value is adjustable) which can then be used to power the module.